# Cakephp display view fields that is set by select elements in form

Tags: php, cakephp, select, cakephp-2.0, formhelper

I am having problem displaying values set by select elements created by `FormHelper`.  I have searched the internet but doesn't seem to be able to find the answer.  Here is the scene:

I have a questionnaire form that has many options.  In the model I put those items into an array, say (`$frequencyOptions`) and when `formhelper` is used,

```
$this->Form->input('frequency',array("options"=> $frequencyOptions));
```

Currently, the option value is the array index, which looks like:

```
    <option value="">(choose one)</option>
    <option value="0">Rare</option>
    <option value="1">Frequent</option>
    <option value="2">Moderate</option>
```

Of course I know that if I set the key as well when constructing the `$frequencyOptions` variable like

```
$frequencyOptions = array("Rare" => "Rare", ...
```

I will be able to store the value in text.

However, since some of these options are very very long, I would prefer to save them in INT in the database.

Yet the challenge I have at this moment is how to display those fields in the "list" in the index page.  When I use the form field to display in the view or edit action, it is okay because the select element will be used again.  However, if I want to display it in plain text, how should I "translate" it?

One thing I can think of is to create these "conversion" methods in the Model, but I think calling model method in views is not a good practice in MVC.

Any idea?

Comment: You can call those "conversion methods" from the controller, which seems fine to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think adding a method to your Model would be the way to go. How about this:

```
// In your Model class

// Store the index-to-name map in the Model as well
var $frequencyOptions = array(...);

public function translateFrequency(&$data) {
    foreach ($data as &$record) {
        $index = $record['ModelName']['frequency'];
        $record['ModelName']['frequency'] = $this->frequencyOptions[$index];
    }
}

// In your Controller action:
$data = $this->ModelName->find(...);
$this->ModelName->translateFrequency($data);
```

And then it should display the human-readable value when passed to the index page. If preferred, the above method could be changed so it works on `$this->data` inside the Model.

*Note:* The method has to be changed if it should work for a single record data array as well.